# Problem disposing the managed resources in c# window form

Tags: c#

In the below code, i am trying to reference an external .dll, which creates a custom taskbar in the desktop. After which i am creating tabs on the taskbar as per my requirement.

Everything works fine, but after i terminate my application for creating the taskbar, the space which is occupied by the custom taskbar is blocked. which means that, the resources are not released after exiting the application.

I am trying the force the application to dispose the unmanaged resources. But it dosent help.
How to do it?? Please refer to the code below which i am trying with...

namespace Daemon
{

```
public partial class MDIParent : ShellLib.ApplicationDesktopToolbar , IDisposable
{

    private static MDIParent MDIParentInstance = null;


    public MDIParent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 50;
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }
    int childCount = 1;
    int iHitcount = 0;


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }


    private void MDIParent_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Taskbar.Show();
    }

    public void TabIt(string strProcessName)
    {
        //Get the collection of opened tab names and check against the new tabs.
        //If exists, dont allow to open the same tab again.

        bool found = false;

        if (Global.ExistingTabProcessNames.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string currentTab in Global.ExistingTabProcessNames)
            {
                if (currentTab.Equals(strProcessName))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (found == false)
        {
            this.Show();

            //Creating MDI child form and initialize its fields
            MDIChild childForm = new MDIChild();
            childForm.Text = strProcessName;
            childForm.MdiParent = this;

            //child Form will now hold a reference value to the tab control
            childForm.TabCtrl = tabControl1;

            //Add a Tabpage and enables it
            TabPage tp = new TabPage();
            tp.Parent = tabControl1;
            tp.Text = childForm.Text;
            tp.Show();
            //child Form will now hold a reference value to a tabpage
            childForm.TabPag = tp;
            //Activate the MDI child form
            childForm.Show();
            childCount++;

            //Activate the newly created Tabpage
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;
            tp.Height = tp.Parent.Height;
            tp.Width = tp.Parent.Width;
        }
    }

    private void MDIParent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Edge = AppBarEdges.Top;
    } 

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]

    private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        iHitcount = iHitcount + 1;
        if (iHitcount != 1)
            BringFront(tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text.ToString());
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
    private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

    private void BringFront(string ExecutablePath)
    {
        Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains(ExecutablePath))
            {

                ShowWindowAsync(clsProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowWindowAsync(clsProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
            }
        }
    }

    public static MDIParent MDIParentRef
    {
        get
        {
            if (MDIParentInstance == null)
                MDIParentInstance = new MDIParent();

            return MDIParentInstance;
        }
    }

    public void showScreen()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.showScreen));
        }
        else
        {

            this.Show();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Global.TabProcessNames.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string strProcessName in Global.TabProcessNames)
            {
                TabIt(strProcessName);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *appbar* is removed by the `OnClosing` event of `ApplicationDesktopToolbar`.

Are you using `Application.Exit` to exit your application? From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx):

> The  `Application.Exit`   method does not raise the  `Form.Closed`   and  `Form.Closing`   events [...]

Comment: This is a windows based application which runs in the background. So, if the user wants to exit the application, he will kill the .exe from taskmanager.

Comment: Yeah, the question is similar to mine, but no solution is provided.
Orelse, it would be better if i dispose globally for the application.

Comment: I believe if the application is killed from Task Manager then it's nearly impossible to run any cleanup code. ... The Vista sidebar doesn't show up in the 'Processes' tab of Task Manager; AFAIK it's run as a Windows Service. Have you thought about turning your application into a service?